# how get the title of a custom post type as link to its related post?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want to get the post title of an custom post type and link it to its related post.
So I`ve got the following code:

```
query_posts( 'post_type=custom_post_type&posts_per_page=1&order=DESC' );

while (have_posts()) : the_post();
       echo "' >"; the_title(); "";

endwhile;
```

the output of the post title works fine, but it is not linking correctly.
do i have a syntax error? or is this method completely wrong?

thanks for help!

Comment: Can you explain how it's "not linking correctly"? Please show the output you currently have versus what you need.

Comment: no post was addressed. it just outputted the link statement as text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `get_permalink()` to obtain the current `$post`'s permalink.

```
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
?>
  <a href="<?= get_permalink() ?>"><?= sanitize_title(get_the_title()) ?></a>
<?php     
endwhile;
```

In case you're using a very outdated PHP version, replace the `<?=` by `<?php echo`.